# How to stop init method being called multiple times in below class implementations?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, singleton, init

Objectives accomplished with below code:

1. Instance created using `A()` and `B()` always results in class B instance.
2. Class B should be Singleton, meaning object initialised using `A()` and `B()` should always return instance with same `id`

Problem to solve:
In case 1, `__init__` method of class B is called thrice and in case 2 `__init__` is called twice.
My requirement: `__init__` method should be called only once during the first instance creation. This first instance creation can be in any of these forms: `A()` or `B()`

Python code:

```
class A:
    _default_impl = None
    _instance = None

    @classmethod
    def set_default_impl(cls, impl_class):
        cls._default_impl = impl_class

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):       
        if cls is A:
            if cls._default_impl is not None:
                if cls._default_impl._instance is None:
                    cls._default_impl._instance = cls._default_impl(*args, **kwargs)
                return cls._default_impl._instance
            else:
                raise TypeError("No implementation is set")
        else:
            if cls._instance is None:
                cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
            return cls._instance

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("Class B implementation")
    def __init__(self):
        print("init called")


A.set_default_impl(B)

# Case 1:
obj1 = A()
obj2 = A()
obj2.foo() # prints: Class B implementation
print("same") if id(obj1) == id(obj2) else print("Not same")

# Case 2: 
obj1 = B()
obj2 = B()
obj2.foo() # prints: Class B implementation
print("same") if id(obj1) == id(obj2) else print("Not same")
```

Making below change in `__init__` method of class B can resolve this issue, but I'm looking for some other solution which will not even invoke the `__init__` method of class B for the second time and hence will help me not to put all the initialization code inside `if not self._initialzed:` condition.

```
class B(A):
    _initialzed = False
    def foo(self):
        print("Class B implementation")
    def __init__(self):
        if not self._initialzed:
            self._initialzed = True
            print("init called")
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Calling `__init__` when instantiating new object is the way Python works. Simple flag that returns if this Singleton was already instantiated is the way to go.

Comment: @matszwecja Thanks for quick reply. I'm not able to figure out where to set the flag and then where to do the condition check. Could you please guide ?

Comment: Check posted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
    def __init__(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'flag'):
            return
        self.flag = True
        # standard initialisation code
```

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'flag'):
            return
        print("init called")
        super().__init__()
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix it from class A so that all child classes of class A need not handle this ?

Comment: @AshinKAjay As long as you don't implement `__init__` for any child classes, this should work. If you do, you will need the guard.